# Replace and mapping string values in a Python dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i've been tryng to replace string values in a dataframe (strings are abbreviation of NFL teams), i have something like this:

```
Index   IDMatch Usr1    Usr2    Usr3    Usr4    Usr5
0       1       Phi     Atl     Phi     Phi     Phi
1       2       Bal     Bal     Bal     Buf     Bal
2       3       Ind     Ind     Cin     Cin     Ind
3       4       NE      NE      Hou     NE      NE
4       5       Jax     Jax     NYG     NYG     NYG
```

and a Dataframe with the mapping, something like this:

```
Index  TEAM_YH  TeamID
0      ARI       1
1      ATL       2
2      BAL       3
...
31     WAS       32
```

I want to replace every string with the TeamID to make basic statistics (frequency), i've tried the next:

```
## Dataframe with strings and Team ID
dfDicTeams = dfTeams[['TEAM_YH','TeamID']].to_dict('dict')

## Dataframe with selections by users
dfW1.replace(dfDicTeams[['TEAM_YH']],dfDicTeams[['TeamID']]) ## Error: unhashable type: 'list'

dfW1.replace(dfDicTeams) ## Error: Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values
```

what am i doing wrong? is it posible to do it?

I'm using Python 3, and i want something like this:

```
Index   IDMatch Usr1    Usr2    Usr3    Usr4    Usr5
0       1       26      2       26      26      26
1       2       3       3       3       4       3
2       3       14      14      7       7       14
3       4       21      21      13      21      21
4       5       15      15      23      23      23
```

to aggregate the options:

```
IDMatch ATeam Count HTeam Count
1       26      4   2       1
2       3       4   4       1
3       14      3   7       2
4       21      4   13      1
5       15      2   23      3
```

Comment: What if the mapping does not exist, like Jax for example.  Does the TeamID actually have a meaning, or does it just have to be different for each team?

Comment: this is a Week pick'em set, every user choose a team as a winner i want to replace the string for the ID of the team. I'll edit my question to show what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a main input dataframe `df` and a mapping dataframe `df_map`, you can create a series mapping, then use [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with a custom function:

```
s = df_map.set_index('TEAM_YH')['TeamID']
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].applymap(lambda x: s.get(x.upper(), -1))

print(df)

   Index  IDMatch  Usr1  Usr2  Usr3  Usr4  Usr5
0      0        1     7     2     7     7     7
1      1        2     3     3     3     4     3
2      2        3     5     5    -1    -1     5
3      3        4    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
4      4        5     6     6    -1    -1    -1
```

The example `df_map` used to calculate the above result:

```
Index  TEAM_YH  TeamID
0      ARI       1
1      ATL       2
2      BAL       3
3      BUF       4
4      IND       5
5      JAX       6
6      PHI       7
32     WAS       32
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, unfortunately it's send error about using upper with float. If i'm not wrong where it says `... s.get(x.upper(),..` you're applyng then function upper, am'm right?

Comment: So you probably have a `NaN` value somewhere, which is considered `float`.  `float` values don't have an `upper` method. Clean your data first is my suggestion, for example replace `NaN` values with an empty string `''`.

Comment: Now it's works, but if it was all the way around? how to pass from int to string?

Comment: @RafaBarragan, You can use `str(x).upper()`, but not recommended..this may convert `NaN` values to `'nan'` string, and who knows, you may have a mapping from `NAN -> some number`. Better to use a ternary statement: `lambda x: np.nan if x != x else s.get(x.upper(), -1)`. Because `np.nan != np.nan`.